# Is It Possible to Set the user.agent Property from the Command Line Using the GWT-Maven-Plugin?

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I know that in my *.gwt.xml file I can specify the browsers I want the GWT compiler to compile my app for by adding this to it:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="opera,ie8, gecko1_8, safari, ie9"/>
```

Is it possible for me to set this property on the command line when I build my project through maven?  I'd like to be able to do something like this when I'm developing locally on my machine:

```
mvn clean install -Duser.agent="opera,ie8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Starting with GWT 2.7, you can now pass a `-setProperty user.agent=…` on the command line; no need to tweak gwt.xml files any more. I'm not sure Mojo Plugin for GWT let you use that though, but the `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` Maven Plugin for GWT can.

---

You can use [filtering of your resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), but then it might make it harder to work from within your IDE.

In your gwt.xml:

```xml
<set-property name="user.agent" value="${user.agent}" />
```

Then in your pom.xml:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

and the default value for the property when you don't give it on the command-line:

```xml
<properties>
  <user.agent>opera,ie8,gecko1_8,safari,ie9</user.agent>
</properties>
```

Note however that this goes against [The Maven Way™](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/04/the-maven-way.html).