# Pass GWT user.agent property to maven command line

Tags: maven, gwt, properties

I have a GWT project and I build it with maven.

```
-T 1C clean install -pl admin-module -am -DskipTests -f pom.xml
```

And I have `admin.gwt.xml` file with this property:

`<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>`

Can I pass this property to maven instead override it in `admin.gwt.xml`?

Something like this:

```
-T 1C clean install -pl admin-module -am -DskipTests -f pom.xml -user.agent=safari
```

I find only one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287929/11926338)  but it does not work for me.

Comment: Regarding the amswer from Thomas Broyer, your command line looks like this:`-T 1C clean install -pl admin-module -am -DskipTests -f pom.xml -setProperty user.agent=safari`. But, as Thomas mentioned it will only work for sure with the  TBroyer maven-gwt-plugin.

Comment: @ElHoss Can you link to that answer? I don't think just plain `-setProperty` will do anything to get it to a maven plugin (though I'd be very glad to learn something new today). At a glance, I'm not seeing anything about setting properties in any of the goals at https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/.

Comment: @Colin Alworth: I found the answer here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287480/is-it-possible-to-set-the-user-agent-property-from-the-command-line-using-the-gw

Comment: From that answer, that is what you would pass as an argument to the Compiler main(), not what you would pass to maven. In that answer, since `user.agent` was declared as a property, you would be able to pass `-Duser.agent=safari`, and restrict the build to only allow the one property value.